# Trying to iterate over lists and nested list to zip items into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterator

I have two lists, one of them contains a view hundred nested lists. I want to combine items of both and zip them into a dict.

**code example:**

```
list1 = ['SYNNR', 'NAME', 'BUNDESLAND']
list2 = [['11032', 'POYSDORF-OST', 'NOE'], ['11033', 'POYSDORF-WEST', 'NOE'], ['11034', 'POYSDORF-NORD', 'NOE']]

#iterate and zip
for i in range(len(list2)):
    result = dict(zip(list1, list2[i]))
print(result)
```

result

`{'SYNNR': '11034', 'NAME': 'POYSDORF-NORD', 'BUNDESLAND': 'NOE'}`

Only the last list inside list2 gets zipped in the dict. but I need to get dict for every list inside list2, like this

`{'SYNNR': '11032', 'NAME': 'POYSDORF-OST', 'BUNDESLAND': 'NOE'}, {'SYNNR': '11033', 'NAME': 'POYSDORF-WEST', 'BUNDESLAND': 'NOE'}, {'SYNNR': '11034', 'NAME': 'POYSDORF-NORD', 'BUNDESLAND': 'NOE'}`

Thanks for ideas!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code only returns the last `dict` that you create. Perhaps, instead of a single `dict`, you wanted a list of dicts:

```py
result = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
    result.append(dict(zip(list1, list2[i])))
print(result)
```

However, as usual, instead of using the `range(len(...` idiom you can express this directly as a list comprehension:

`result = [dict(zip(list1, line)) for line in list2]`

Comment: Thanks, your right I forgot to append into a new list. Now its working:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overwriting the result variable for every item in the list, instead, you should have an array of dictionaries for the result variable

```
#iterate and zip
result = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
    result.append(dict(zip(list1, list2[i])))
print(result)
```

Another, optional improvement you could do is to simplify the first for, that would improve readability

```
result = []
for item in list2:
    result.append(dict(zip(list1, item)))
print(result)
```